# DNS incosistent

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, dns, mapr

I am trying to create a MAPR cluster, nut I have [DNS inconsistent warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrdO7.png). I have edited my /etc/hosts file as

```
10.0.0.10 master.aptus.com
10.0.0.20 slave1.aptus.com
10.0.0.30 slave2.aptus.com
```

These system contribute to establishing cluster. When i execute :

```
host 10.0.0.10
```

the output is:

```
10.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa has no PTR record
```

And when I execute :

```
host master.aptus.com
```

I get the following output :

```
master.aptus.com has address 128.199.41.186
```

I tried to run the installation with warning, but installation fails.
[MAPR installation fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2cL5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update DNS entry in domain server

Update the DNS server (AD server) with the new ip address for the cluster node which is being migrated. Once it is updated, all the nodes in the cluster will be able to resolve it.

Check the reverse lookup zone and make sure it is the same using dns tool or ssh

Try it let me know if it helps.